# I can't use the right click of my notebook in ubuntu 12.04, how can I correct this?

Tags: 12.04, touchpad

if I'm trying to click right with my touchpad (of my Packard Bell EasyNote TX) in Ubuntu (in Windows 7 everything works fine) I'm only doing a left click. maybe the left click is caused by the all-over-touchpad (there's also touchpad on the left and the right button) but however, I can't click right.

(I'm a Ubuntu Newbie)

Comment: Melina hasn't signed on in 5+ years. Question is about Ubuntu 12.04 which is EOL. Question address Packard Bell Touchpad which is probably out of business. VTC as `not reproducible`.